# Same Winforms .Net binary uses much more memory on one PC and doesn't release it (GC not working maybe?)

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have a problem with an application that's driving me crazy, and I really don't know what else I can do to investigate further.

I've got a simple Windows Forms application (32-bit, VB.net, Framework 4.5.1) behaving very strangely on **only one PC**, regarding memory allocation. On all other PCs I tried it's working fine! There *MUST* be something on that particular PC, but I'm at a loss how to figure out what it is, short of reinstalling everything one by one...

So, on all PCs **except one**, the memory utilization of the application is fine and doesn't go above **10-20 Megabytes.** On one PC only, which happens to be my own development PC, the memory keeps increasing and never gets released, until it reaches the 2 GB Windows limit and throws an Out of Memory exception. I copied the exact same binaries on 6 different PCs (four Win7, two Win10), and confirmed that the application is behaving fine (and consistently) on all those PCs. On my own PC only, even when the application starts without initiating the transfer, it seems to be occupying at least 20 megabytes more compared to other PCs. So whatever it is, must be something on the PC which is causing this.

The app is using an `SqlDataReader` with `SqlBulkCopy` to transfer several gigabytes of data from one database to another. The transfer is done month by month. All the SqlDataReader, SqlBulkCopy, SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects are disposed after each month, since I'm enclosing them in a `Using` block. I'm even calling `GC.Collect` at the end of each iteration.

I even used Visual Studio's memory profiler to try and figure out what's happening, but all it's saying is that the majority of the memory is requested by the `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` command. This doesn't seem to be particularly insightful.

Now here's another interesting note: If I use the Winapi method [`EmptyWorkingSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-emptyworkingset) after every iteration (not shown in code below), the memory seems to be getting released. So why on earth doesn't Dotnet's Garbage Collector do the same, as expected and why only on one PC???

Here's the code. Some parts modified to remove confidential stuff.
It's a VB.Net Winforms application using .Net Framework 4.5.1. It's build on VS 2017, Windows 10.

Any advise on how on earth to investigate this further, short of starting to remove Windows Updates and other software one-by-one from that particular workstation, would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

```vb
Private Sub CopyData()

    ' Database connection strings for source and destination db
    Dim conn_string_source As String = "<CONFIDENTIAL DATA MASKED>",
        conn_string_destination As String = "<CONFIDENTIAL DATA MASKED>"

    ' For progress report.
    Dim rows_total As Long,
        rows_done As Long

    '
    ' Find total rows to transfer.
    ' For progress report.
    '
    Using _
        conn_src As New SqlConnection(conn_string_source),
        cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Count(*) From dbo.SOURCE_TABLE", conn_src)
        rows_total = CLng(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        Console.WriteLine("{0:#,##0} total rows to transfer.", rows_total)
    End Using

    '
    ' Transfer rows for one year, one month at a time.
    ' Dispose connections, readers and bulkcopy class at end of each month.
    '
    For which_month = 1 To 12

        Using _
            conn_dest As New SqlConnection(conn_string_destination),
            conn_src As New SqlConnection(conn_string_source),
            bc = New SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(conn_dest)

            '
            ' For progress report.
            ' Calculate rows for this month.
            '
            Dim rows_this_month As Long
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand("Select  Count(*) 
                                        From    dbo.SOURCE_TABLE 
                                        Where   posting_month = @mm", conn_src)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mm", which_month)
                rows_this_month = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            End Using

            '
            ' Setup the Bulk Copy operation
            '
            bc.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TARGET_TABLE"
            bc.BulkCopyTimeout = 0      ' Never timeout
            bc.BatchSize = 3000         ' Rows per batch. This values seems efficient enough.
            bc.NotifyAfter = 250        ' Raise notification event after every this number of rows copies.
            ' Microsoft says for better memory usage, though tests indicate doesn't make difference.
            bc.EnableStreaming = True

            ' Notify us every few rows to know how much was finished.
            AddHandler bc.SqlRowsCopied,
                Sub(sndr, rr)
                    Console.WriteLine("      ...{0:#,##0} / {1:#,##0}", rr.RowsCopied, rows_this_month)
                End Sub

            '
            ' Perform the actual transfer.
            ' Feed a reader to the SqlBulkCopy operation.
            '
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * 
                                            From   dbo.SOURCE_TABLE 
                                            Where  posting_month = @mm", conn_src)

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mm", which_month)
                Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    bc.WriteToServer(rdr)
                End Using

            End Using

            rows_done += rows_this_month
            Console.WriteLine("      GRAND TOTAL: {0:#,##0} / {1:#,##0}", rows_done, rows_total)

        End Using

        GC.Collect()

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: And you copied the exe on your machine from a working machine? How about framework versions etc, and bitness - do your/other machines all use 32/64 bit consistently?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for replying. I assume the DotNet versions are consistent throughout because they're deployed organization-wide via Microsoft's SCCM. I tried switching between .Net Frameworks 4.6, 4.6.1 and 4.7 but results are the same. I even tried copying all the used framework's assemblies on the application directory (used the "Copy" option on VS references to get the DLLs). Still the same.

Comment: You said the faulty Pc is your dev machine - are you running this app in VS?

Comment: I tried both: Running it from **within** VS, **outside** the VS with all VS instances closed, and both compiled in **Debug** and **Release** mode.

Comment: use .net memory tracing tool on that 1 PC to see what is causing memory leak

Comment: @magicandre1981 I used Visual Studio's .Net memory profiler, and it only says that the majority of memory is held by the SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer command. This to me seems to indicate that the Garbage Collector isn't releasing the memory as I would expect (since I'm disposing the SqlBulkCopy class and the SqlDataReader after each loop iteration). But I have no idea why could that be...